# Change drawable color programmatically for each item in list

Tags: android, android-layout, android-recyclerview, background-color

I`ve a recycler with custom CircleView and some part in right side. I need to change right side background color for each item programmatically. Every item in list must have its own color.

[image]

Item`s right side code:

```
 <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    android:id="@+id/card_rarity_info"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="78dp"
    android:background="@drawable/shape_rarity"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@id/circle_rarity_color"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/circle_rarity_color"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/circle_rarity_color"
    tools:backgroundTint="@color/colorPrimary">

    <TextView ... />

    <TextView ... />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Setting backgroundTint in recycler view adapter:

```
override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: RaritiesViewHolder, position: Int) {
    ...
    rarities[position].color?.let {
        holder.cardRarityInfo.background.setTint(Color.parseColor("#$it"))
    }
}
```

But result incorrect! It set up the last item color for every item in list

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just need to use `mutate()` for drawable.

That's why every item have same color:

> By default, all drawables instances loaded from the same resource share a common state; if you modify the state of one instance, all the other instances will receive the same modification.

When I use `mutate()` for recycler items in adapter, it produce states for every single item in list.

Usage:

```
override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: SomeViewHolder, position: Int) {
    rarities[position].color?.let {
        holder.circleView.setCircleColor(it) // custom view fun which take HEX parse it and invalidate
        holder.cardInfo.background.run {
            mutate()
            setTint(Color.parseColor("#$it"))
        }
    }
    <...>
}
```

For more information [article](https://medium.com/@grzesiek.matyszczak/how-to-modify-drawables-programmatically-on-android-e851c74cc74e) and [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/Drawable#mutate())